# Im getting troubles with my command of pinging online people

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i have a command (code down there) that pings the members with a specific role and with a specific status. A week ago it was working, but i think discord.py updated and i cant use that format anymore.

Old Code:

```
@client.command()
async def moderator(ctx, *, arg):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)
    online = (member for member in role.members if member.status == discord.Status.online or discord.Status.idle)
    for member in online:
        await member.send(f'{member.mention} Moderator Requested by {ctx.author} Reason: {arg}')
```

i hope you can help me.

Comment: You coded the first one, what hinders you to adjust to the new api?

Comment: yeah i just dont know how to adjust and i dont even know if that is the problem, i just think it is

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled? In the code and the developer portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new update, they changed some of the intents default to False and you need to activate it yourself to access members and presences.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

bot: commands.Bot = commands.Bot(
    intents=intents,
    ## and any other key word argument you have like prefix or ...
)
```

Document:

> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents
> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents

---

I noticed you have a logic error in your check:

```py
    online = (member for member in role.members if member.status == discord.Status.online or discord.Status.idle)
```

More specific:

```py
if member.status == discord.Status.online or discord.Status.idle
```

It is the same as this line:

```py
if (member.status == discord.Status.online) or discord.Status.idle
```

Since `discord.Status.idle` will be always `True` as a condition this condition is always `True`
This is the condition you want to check:

```py
if member.status in (discord.Status.online, discord.Status.idle)
```

Comment: ohh i forgot the ```intents.presences = True``` thanks im sooooo dumb

Comment: the thing is it works with ```online = (member for member in role.members if member,status == discord.Status.online)``` but it doesnt with ```online = (member for member in role.members if member..status == discord.Status.online or discord.Status.idle)``` and i dont know what is

Comment: @Tacabeu it is a logical problem and I don't know why people always do this, I'll edit my answer with the fix

Comment: thx solved ur the best

Comment: The `or` functionality is interesting, I recommend test some examples in idle and see what is the outcome. For example `[1, 2] or [4, 5]` is almost the same as your phrase `online or idle`. As result, it will pass only the online list if it is not empty, else it will pass only the idle list. Use `for member in online + idle:` instead or the code I posted in the answer